# Bluez Obex daemon not starting

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, bluez

my Bluez obexd daemon is not starting. I connect via:

```
ssh -X something@something
```

I have a running dbus user session and set the `DISPLAY` env var with `DISPLAY=:0` like the www told me. My `daemon.log` tells me:

> obexd[28116]: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Raspbian but without PIXEL. I installed X11 and can run applications like Chromium via ssh on my Mac. The obex daemon is the only thing that is not working right now...

Any hints on what might be wrong or how to debug this?